# Display one user's information from a database table in android studio

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm currently building an android app and I have seen plenty of advice online about how to return rows of database data as list view in android but I am simply wanting to return one field.

Basically, a user logs in with their username and password. Each username is unique.

On the next screen, I want a textView which displays their real name, taken from the db table based on their username but I am struggling to find out how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The php file looks like this:

```
<?php
$user="";
$server="";
$db="";
$password=""; [I have removed these to share this]

$conn=mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);

$query="SELECT * FROM rest_users WHERE username = 'XXX'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error: '+mysql.error());

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response, array("name"=>$row[1], "table"=>$row[5]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($conn);
```

The 'XXX' is obviously where I want the username to be from the details entered in the login screen.

The below is the relevant code from the activity where I want the name displayed:

```
 public void getJSON(View view){
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String jsonurl;
        String JSON_STRING;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            jsonurl = "http://mgourley03.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/RestaurantApp/json/jsongetdata.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(jsonurl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null){
                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(result);
            json_string = result;
        }


    }

    public void parseJSON(View view){
        if(json_string==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First get JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomerHomeScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

I was originally following an online tutorial but it was going to return all values in list view which isn't what I wanted. I was hoping there would be another method to just return the user's name from the table using their username (which I have passed through using intent.putExtra on the login activity)

Comment: Show the code what you have tried.

Comment: Edited my original post to show the code too!